# Output row for each input in a column Pentaho Data Integration Spoon

Tags: pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I am new to Pentaho Data Integration, and I am looking to take the below column data and have an output for each entry in the date columns. Not sure how this can be done in spoon.

I have looked into the Denormalisation step, but examples are not very good that I have found. Also, I am not sure it would get me an output for each column value.

Starting Data: 
[image: StartingData]

Desired Data: 
[image: DesiredData]

[Pentaho Forum version with sample files attached.](https://forums.pentaho.com/showthread.php?230337-Output-row-for-each-input-in-a-column-Pentaho-Data-Integration-Spoon&p=467367#post467367)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this I found out you need to use the normaliser step with the below settings.

[image: SettingsForNormaliser]

Results:

[image: DesiredData]